# How to shrink size of HDFS in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

Iam using Hadoop to parse ample(about 1 million) text files and each has lot of data into it.
Firstly I uploaded all my text files into hdfs using Eclipse. But when uploading the files, my map-reduce operation resulted in huge amount of files in following directory  C:\tmp\hadoop-admin\dfs\data.
So , is there any mechanism, using which I can shrink the size of my HDFS (basically above mentioned drive).

Answer (score 0):

to shrink your HDFS size you can set a greater value (in bytes) to following `hdfs-site.xml` property

```
 dfs.datanode.du.reserved=0
```

You can also lower the amount of data generated by map outputs by enabling map output compression.

```
map.output.compress=true
```

hope that helps.